# fortran, how to make several copies of a program using module or interface?

Tags: syntax, fortran, fortran77

I want to do a double integration using **`CGAUSS`**, a FORTRAN program in `cernlib`. I have to make two copies *`CGAUSS1` and `CGAUSS2`* in order to avoid `CGAUSS` call itself.

But I do not find the original `CGAUSS` code. Is there a way to make copies using module or interface in FORTRAN?

Comment: The source code can be downloaded from http://cernlib.web.cern.ch/cernlib/version.html

Comment: @M.S.B. Thank you. But I cannot find the .f file there. Can you find?

Comment: Follow 2006 -- compressed tar files.  Download 2006_src.tar.gz.  Un gzip and untar.  directory has the files cgauss.F, cgauss64.F, cgauss128.F.

Comment: @M.S.B. According to your suggestion, I have found the code. Thank you very much!