# Fortran, How to make several copies a procedure

Tags: function, fortran, double, integration, procedures

I have a function (Simpson) that calculates the integral of a function (f (x, y = 5)). I want to use this same function (Simpson) to make a double integration of the function f (x, y):

F(x) = \int dy f(x,y) 
   I = \int dx F(x)

Could I call the same function twice (Simpson) in Fortran?
How would I do this in the example that I put down?
I think the main idea of my question has already been made here but I have not found the answer.
[fortran, how to make several copies of a program using module or interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946259/fortran-how-to-make-several-copies-of-a-program-using-module-or-interface)

I'm not interested in making a copy of the function Simpson: Simpson1 Simpson2 neither to use an external package.

Best

This is the outline of the code that I'm using:

```
MODULE INTEG
IMPLICIT NONE
CONTAINS
REAL FUNCTION SIMPSON(FUNC,A,B,TOL)
    REAL, INTENT(IN) :: A, B, TOL
    INTERFACE
      FUNCTION FUNC (X) RESULT(OUT)
            IMPLICIT NONE
            REAL, INTEN(IN) :: X
            REAL :: OUT
       END FUNCTION 
    END INTERFACE
........
END FUNCTION SIMPSON 
END MODULE INTEG

MODULE DOING
USE INTEG
REAL :: TEMP
IMPLICIT NONE
CONTAINS
REAL FUNCTION  FUNC (X,Y) 
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL, INTENT(IN) :: X, Y
    REAL :: OUT
    FUNC =  X*Y
END FUNCTION FUNC

FUNCTION F(Y) RESULT(OUT2)
    REAL, INTENT(IN) :: Y
    REAL :: A, B, TOL,OUT2
    TEMP = Y
    OUT2 = SIMPSON(I1, A, B, TOL)
    CONTAINS
    REAL FUNCTION I1(X) RESULT(OUT)
        REAL, INTENT(IN) :: X
        OUT = FUNC (X,TEMP) 
    END FUNCTION I1
END FUNCTION F

    REAL FUNCTION I2(A2, B2, TOL2)
        REAL, INTENT(IN) :: A2, B2, TOL2
        I2 = SIMPSON(F, A2, B2,TOL)
    END FUNCTION I2 
END MODULE DOING

PROGRAM EXAMPLE
USE DOING
IMIPLICIT NONE
REAL :: A2, B2, TOL2, OUT3
OUT3 =  I2(A2, B2, TOL2)
END PROGRAM EXAMPLE
```

Comment: Please use the generic [tag:fortran] tag unless your question is specific to a certain version of the Fortran Standard.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You can call a function how many times you want. Please clarify your problem. Have you tried anything? Did you get some error?

Answer (score 0):

Alexander you're right.I made a mistake at some point. The following code is working

```
MODULE INTEG 
    IMPLICIT NONE
    CONTAINS
    REAL FUNCTION Simpson(FUN, A, B, N)
        IMPLICIT NONE
        INTERFACE
            FUNCTION FUN (X) RESULT(RESUL)
               IMPLICIT NONE
               REAL, INTENT(IN) :: X
               REAL :: RESUL 
            END FUNCTION FUN
        END INTERFACE
        INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: N
        REAL, INTENT(IN) :: A, B

        INTEGER :: N1, N2, I
        REAL :: STEP, H, SUMA1, SUMA2

        H = (B-A)/REAL(N)

        N1 = N/2 - 1
        N2 = N/2

        SUMA1 = 0.0
        DO I = 1, N1
            STEP = A + 2*I*H
            SUMA1 = SUMA1 + FUN(STEP)
        END DO
        SUMA2 = 0.0
        DO I = 1, N2
            STEP = A + (2*I-1)*H
            SUMA2 = SUMA2 + FUN(STEP)
        END DO
       Simpson = H*( FUN(A) + 2*SUMA1 + 4*SUMA2 + FUN(B) )/3.0
   END FUNCTION Simpson   
END MODULE INTEG

MODULE DOING
    USE INTEG
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL :: TEMP
    CONTAINS
    REAL FUNCTION  FUNC (X,Y) 
        IMPLICIT NONE
        REAL, INTENT(IN) :: X, Y
        REAL :: OUT
        FUNC =  X*Y
    END FUNCTION FUNC

    FUNCTION F(Y) RESULT(OUT2)
      REAL, INTENT(IN) :: Y
      REAL :: A, B, TOL,OUT2
      TEMP = Y
      A = 1
      B = 3
      OUT2 = Simpson(I1, A, B, 100)
      CONTAINS
      REAL FUNCTION I1(X) RESULT(OUT)
         REAL, INTENT(IN) :: X
         OUT = FUNC (X,TEMP) 
      END FUNCTION I1
   END FUNCTION F

  REAL FUNCTION I2(A2, B2, NN)
     REAL, INTENT(IN) :: A2, B2
     INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: NN
     I2 = Simpson(F, A2, B2,100)
  END FUNCTION I2 
END MODULE DOING

PROGRAM EXAMPLE
  USE DOING
  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL :: A2, B2, OUT3
  A2 = 1
  B2 = 3
  OUT3 =  I2(A2, B2, 100)
  WRITE(*,*)OUT3
END PROGRAM EXAMPLE
```